# Why does Javascript readline question method read more than one line when wrapped in a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, readline

Why does Javascript readline `question` method read more than one line when wrapped in a Promise?

The code below is supposed to simply add line numbers to the input.  It works as expected if I run it and type the input at the command line. However, if I redirect a file into the process, then it consumes the entire file at once.  Why is that?

Expected output:

```
Next line, please: File line 1
1       File line 1
Next line, please: File line 2
2       File line 2
Next line, please: File line 3
3       File line 3
Next line, please: File line 4
4       File line 4
Next line, please: Input stream closed.
```

Observed output (when running `node testReadline.mjs < the_file.txt`)

```
Next line, please: File line 1
File line 2
File line 3
File line 4
1       File line 1
Next line, please: Input stream closed.
```

It appears to be consuming the entire file after the first call to `question`, rather than consuming only one line at a time.

(I know there is the `readline/promises` package.  I'm curious why the code below doesn't behave as expected.)

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline';

const io = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

io.on('close', () => {console.log("Input stream closed.")});

let questionWrapper = (prompt) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        io.question(prompt, (line) => {
            resolve(line)
        });
    });
}

let printLine_await = async () => {
    let line_num = 1;
    while(true) {
        let line = await questionWrapper('Next line, please: ');
        console.log(`${line_num}\t${line}`)
        line_num++;
    }
}

printLine_await(1)
```

---

For what it's worth, I get the expected result when using callbacks.

This code

```
let printLine_callback = (line_num) => {
    io.question('Next line, please: ', (line) => {
        console.log(`${line_num}\t${line}`)
        printLine_callback(line_num + 1)
    })
}
```

Produces this result:

```
Next line, please: File line 1
1       File line 1
Next line, please: File line 2
2       File line 2
Next line, please: File line 3
3       File line 3
Next line, please: File line 4
4       File line 4
Next line, please: Input stream closed.
```

It's not clear from the documentation what is supposed to happen if the input ends while `question` is waiting; but, the behavior I see makes sense in this case (where the file ends with a newline).

Comment: @Zack "*when wrapped in a Promise*" feels like a red herring. Or do you have evidence that it works as expected when not using promises but callback style?

Comment: Only the first line callback of each input's `data` event is actually called asynchronously, all others are called sync. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v18.10.0/lib/internal/readline/interface.js#L614

Comment: I first was wondering why I couldn't see where *promises.js* did the magic, but after testing, I get the same result with */promises* than with your wrapper...

Comment: @Bergi It does work as expected when using callbacks only.  (See edit above.)

Comment: @Kaiido What is the significance of only the first line being called asynchronously.  Does that suggest a bug / limitation of the library, or is there something I can do to get the expected behavior?

Comment: I must admit I'm not 100% familiar with this lib, and from what I read here and there it seems that `question()` may not be the best way to do what you're doing... However I didn't find what would be that "best way", hence no answer from me, yet. And regarding the significance of having all other callbacks fired sync this means that when your (and `readline/promises`'s) code return Promises from the callbacks, these Promises's `.then()` will all get executed after all the initial callbacks fired, i.e after the stream has ended being read entirely.

Comment: "*I know there is the readline/promises package*" - from studying its code, I would think its `.question()` method has exactly the same problem. The only advantage is that it's cancellable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kaiido noticed, if the input stream `data` event contains multiple lines together (as will be the case when piping a file into the process, with a stream chunk size much larger then the average line length), the `line` events fire all at once. [It's just a synchronous loop](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v18.10.0/lib/internal/readline/interface.js#L614).

The `question` method more or less attaches the callback as a once-only `line` event handler. (It will be called *instead* of firing a `line` event, but that's just a detail). The problem with using a promise to wait for the question's answer is that when the promise is fulfilled, it takes an extra tick of the event loop until the code after the `await` gets to run, which would attach the next `line` handler. But with multiple lines entered at once, those `line` events will have fired *before* the `question()` could be called again. You can verify this by adding

```
io.on('line', line => { console.log("Ignore\t"+line); });
```

> Is there something I can do to get the expected behavior?

When using the `question()` method, not really. However, [what it does](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v18.10.0/lib/internal/readline/interface.js#L404-L416) is rather trivial, so you can replace it by your own working version. I would recommend to use the [async iterator of `readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator) which does the necessary buffering and can be consumed using `async`/`await` syntax. For your demo, the equivalent code would be

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline';

const io = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
let line_num = 1;
io.setPrompt('Next line, please: ');
io.prompt()
for await (const line of io) {
    console.log(`${line_num}\t${line}`)
    line_num++;
    io.prompt()
}
console.log("Input stream closed.")
```

More generally, for scripts that are not just a single loop, I'd do

```
const iterator = io[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
function question(query) {
    const old = io.getPrompt();
    io.setPrompt(query);
    io.prompt();
    const {done, value} = await iterator.next();
    io.setPrompt(old);
    if (done) throw new Error('EOF'); // or something?
    return value;
}
```