# Why is my 'await' line not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, readline

Here is my code in Node.JS

```js
  const fs = require('fs');
  const readline = require('readline');
  const filePath = 'the/path/to/the/file';
  const linesPerChunk = 20;
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  let lines = [];

  rl.on('line', async (line) => {
    lines.push(JSON.parse(line));

    if (lines.length === linesPerChunk) {
      await processLines(lines);
      lines = [];
    }
  });

  rl.on('close', async () => {
    // Process any remaining lines (less than chunk size)
    if (lines.length > 0) {
      await processLines(lines);
    }
  });

  async function processLines(lines) {
    console.log("process lines");
    // Do something with the lines (e.g., print them)
    try {
      const returnData = await someaction();
      console.log(returnData);
      console.log('Done for a chunk.');
      return returnData;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

The first pass goes well but on the line `lines = [];` the whole file is loaded in the `lines` variable as if the system had kept processing new lines even though I'm supposed to `await` the result of the function before processing more lines.

It then immediately goes into the `close` event and tries to process the whole file at once (hence trying to reprocess the chunk I've already processed in addition to all the other ones).

What am I missing here ?
I would like each chunk to be processed one by one in a sequential manner (or in parallel in fact but guaranteeing that no single line gets processed several times).

Comment: Readline won't wait for the promise returned by the event handler. And you have a classical data race by checking `lines.length` *before* an `await` but setting `lines = []` *after* it.

Comment: Thks for replying - How do you propose I solve that issue ?

Comment: `const temp = lines; lines = []; processLines(temp)` would avoid the reprocessing issue. However, while running the `processLines` calls concurrently, you would also not know when processing has finished, and you would not be able to handle errors, due to the promises being ignored. I would recommend sequential, non-chunked processing using the stream as an async iterator, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63753901/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74083585/1048572)

Comment: Thks ! If I process line by line it takes too much time - the processing involves a network call so I absolutely need the chunk aspect. Think I will try the `pause` `resume` way and see if it solves my issue.

Comment: You can also aggregate lines into chunks using `for await`, it's just that `await` is blocking processing so all chunks will be handled sequentially. I had thought you'd only do the chunking to get some parallel processing, not to reduce the number of network calls.

Comment: I got it to do what I wanted with a combination of `pause` and `resume` and using the `then` `catch` pattern on my async processing function.
I still have the issue that the last chunk gets processed twice when my chunk size is a divisor of my total number of lines.... Thank you very much for your pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> The first pass goes well but on the line lines = []; the whole file is
> loaded in the lines variable as if the system had kept processing new
> lines even though I'm supposed to await the result of the function
> before processing more lines.

You are using streams and await only defer processing for any async operation until it is completed. You need to pause and unpause the streams while you process it. This is one way of doing it.

Another solution could be to use [transform stream](https://blog.logrocket.com/working-node-js-streams/) if you want to do some processing for incoming line.

By default readline interface somehow not support the pause on it, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341050/pausing-readline-in-node-js) using a TP library.

Comment: Thks for replying - I want to do some processing on chunks of lines. Is that possible in the transform stream ?

Comment: Yes, you can update the transform function as per your need and pass the updated data to callback.

Answer (score -1):

"By applying this code,the 'someAction' function returns a promise, and the 'processLines' function awaits the completion of this promise before moving on to the next chunk. This should help ensure that each chunk is processed sequentially "

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const filePath = 'the/path/to/the/file';
const linesPerChunk = 20;
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: readStream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

let lines = [];

rl.on('line', async (line) => {
  lines.push(JSON.parse(line));

  if (lines.length === linesPerChunk) {
    await processLines(lines);
    lines = [];
  }
});

rl.on('close', async () => {'
  if (lines.length > 0) {
    await processLines(lines);
  }
});

async function processLines(lines) {
  console.log("process lines");'
  try {
    const returnData = await someAction(lines);
    console.log(returnData);
    console.log('Done for a chunk.');
    return returnData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function someAction(lines) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {'
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Simulating some asynchronous action");
      resolve('Result of the asynchronous action');
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Whom are you quoting?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only changed the `someAction` implementation? That does not solve the issue.